# Family Tree project javafx

Tags: javafx

I have searched ALL the web for an answer and gave up. So my last hope is to find an answer here!!!
I have started to make a Family Tree project using JAVAFX (NOT FXML) and I am stocked in the middle!!!
I have the functionality written in JAVA and can not implement it on JAVAFX. For example the "ADD BUTTON" or "EDIT BUTTON" or ....

Here is the link to all the project: [The Codes](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8J4wpxtz0-LflFtNmw1YVFXVzlzbHpqMVVNTUdDdjcxb3VBYWFXZDRNNXZGVjlCSmRRZk0&authuser=0)

Basically this is the part that i get confused, To use the java method in javafx:

```
Button AddButton = new Button("Add");
Button DeleteButton = new Button("Delete");
Button EditButton = new Button("Edit");


/**
 * Adding a person to the family tree
 */





public void addPerson(Person aPerson) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (Person p : family) {
        if (p.compareTo(aPerson) == 1) {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        family.add(aPerson);
        System.out.println(aPerson.getName() + " has been added!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error 301 - Person already in the family tree.");
    }
}
```

Any help will be truly appreciated !!!!!
Cheers

Comment: [ask] It is expected to have your current attempt (the important parts where you think the problem is) preferably as a working example included in the question and not just a link as an external site. On the other hand -by your description- this is a too broad question for this site.

Comment: For example this https://code.google.com/p/javafx-treechart/

Comment: What is the question here? Are you asking how to invoke your `addPerson` method when the `addButton` is pressed?

Answer (score 1):

Just register a handler with the button:

```
addButton.setOnAction(e -> {
    Person personToAdd = ... ;
    addPerson(personToAdd);
});
```

See the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/button.htm#CJHEEACB).